# How to add Google ads to PhoneGap built apps?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ads, phonegap-build

I have this simple puzzle game that I had developed in JavaScript a while back. I heard about PhoneGap just very recently and thought maybe I could convert it into a native looking app for the Android and the iOS. It turns out that it's quite simple! This brings me to my question: Considering I am new to PhoneGap and have no experience in Android or iOS app development, is it possible to use AdMob or AdSense (I'm not sure if this is the right one) to add interstitials to a PhoneGap built app?

*I know this question was asked before on StackOverflow but there were no answers yet (as of now) so here I am asking again.*

Comment: You will need admob for sure google adds are only for web. Please refer the guidelines of google adsense. :). You can get the admon plugin for phonegap from  http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=admob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use admob, google doesn't allow to use adsense on mobile apps and could ban your account.

If you want to integrate admob, you have plenty plugins available http://plugins.cordova.io/#/search?search=admob